# Dojo huge footprint- Am I doing something wrong

Tags: dojo

I am making a web application using dojo toolkit and heres my code

```
dojo.ready(
 function(){
 dojo.declare("Main",null,{
_dialog:null,
constructor: function()
{
    dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
},
make_dialog: function(url)
{
    _dialog= new dijit.Dialog({
        href:url,
    });
    _dialog.show();
}
}); // class ends

temp=new Main();
});// dojo.ready ends
```

My problem is that when I load dijit.Dialog it is loading various js files( 20 plus) like
tooltip.js,backgroundIframe.js taking about 60kb alone. I want to ask is it dojo normal behaviour or I am doing

And my main problem Is that it making 55 different request. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom build will package everything up into a fewer files.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/custom-builds.html